# Heroku Contacts App: node server.js fails to run

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I got the project from the [Heroku startup guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mean-apps-restful-api) and deployed it successfully. However when I try to run it locally I'm faced with this error:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@2.15.5
3 info using node@v4.4.5
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info prestart MEAN@1.0.0
6 info start MEAN@1.0.0
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info MEAN@1.0.0 Failed to exec start script
9 verbose stack Error: MEAN@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
9 verbose stack Exit status 1
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program    Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:217:16)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
9 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
10 verbose pkgid MEAN@1.0.0
11 verbose cwd C:\Users\kmagl\Documents\CuttingEdge\new-project4
12 error Windows_NT 10.0.10586
13 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
14 error node v4.4.5
15 error npm  v2.15.5
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 error MEAN@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
17 error Exit status 1
18 error Failed at the MEAN@1.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
18 error This is most likely a problem with the MEAN package,
18 error not with npm itself.
18 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
18 error     node server.js
18 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
18 error     npm bugs MEAN
18 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
18 error
18 error     npm owner ls MEAN
18 error There is likely additional logging output above.
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I would love some help on this. I and some other people are having trouble at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you've run `npm install` locally, and that you have an environment variable named MONGODB_URI that has a valid URL to a running mongodb instance.

Also, if you call `node server.js` from the command line, you may find more verbose logging to help you narrow down the problem; the one npm emits is usually pretty opaque.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I have installed the nessecary dependencies. I'll have to check the MONGODB_URI. Looking into the server.js the URI is called I just can't remember how my computer is out away. Will look back into it tomorrow.